# C# Unity Dependency Injection doesn't resolve the same object but creating new one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm injecting one service to my controller and I'm resolving the same service manually, but this two services are not the same. Manually created service is disposing but auto resolved service is not disposing. Let me show by code.

Here is controller, there is a IFirmService auto resolved and I have an other IFirmService in test function manually resolved. Here occurs the problem, there is two IFirmService resolved by unity but they are not the same.

```
public class TestmeController : ApiController
{
    IFirmService FirmServiceHeader;
    public TestmeController(IFirmService _FirmServiceHeader)
    {
        //here is successfully resolved FirmService by unity resolver.
        this.FirmServiceHeader = _FirmServiceHeader;
    }

    [Route("api/test")]
    public IHttpActionResult test() {
        //Here is I'm resolving an other service manually.
        IFirmService FirmServiceLocal = this.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IFirmService)) as IFirmService;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(FirmServiceLocal,FirmServiceHeader)) {
            //Here is the problem, FirmServiceLocal and firmServiceHeader is not resolved as the same
        }

    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**
I'm setting the default DependencyResolver as Unity and setting registered types.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{   
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        .....
        UnityContainr container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IFirmService, FirmService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        //setting the dependency resolver.
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
        .....
    }
}
```

I'm not writing here IFirmService and FirmService class, it is a disposable class.

Summary; I want to resolve the same Firmservice in test() function. And I want to it automaticly disposed after each web api request.

What is the best way for this?

Comment: Why you want to resolve the dependency again in action method if you want it to be the same? Why can't you use the one which is defined at the controller level? If you want the object to be disposed after each request you need to use proper lifetime manager while registering type in Unity. The proper lifetime manager would be `PerRequestLifetimeManager`. This will resolve new object of `FirmService` for every new request.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it is only a sample code. I don't use two service int the same controller, I have tried to simplifyv it. Also thank you for your response.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm getting this error when I try PerRequestLifetimeManager Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'PerRequestLifetimeManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to install nuget package "Unity.Mvc" by microsoft in your project. Class `PerRequestLifetimeManager` is part of assembly `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc`.

Comment: With a quick check I can confirm that it works :) Thank you @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, But it doesn't disposing the service after request completed. I think this solution is not working 100%?

Comment: What is the reason you want to make sure of it's disposal? How are you making sure that it is not disposing? Let the GC take care of it. What is the definition of 100% working solution in this case?

Comment: I'm creating a new DBContext for each service, So I want to be sure if the context created for each request and destroyed at request complete. I'm putting a breakpoint on Dispose() function, but It breakpoint doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if you can make sure of disposal by that way. You might want to put some logging statements in Dispose() method to make sure it's executing. But you might not hit the break point for sure. Anyways if MS has provided the liftimemanager and if you are using it properly you need to be rest assure of it's functionality. One more suggestion would be to register the DbContext in Unity (if you are doing all) also with PerRequestLifeTimeManager. Let me know if you want to discuss this over chat. We will be soon moved to chat automatically from here.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I think it works good with MVC, but It has some problems on Hangfire Jobs. I'm going to try to fix it.

Comment: is unity Must ?

Comment: Yes, I have allready implemented it. What do you think? There is a better injector than Unity?

Answer (score 1):

if you want same object, you should get from same container(UnityContainer).

**[msdn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpblI.png) says about HierarchicalLifetimeManager:**

"The distinction is that when there are child containers, each child resolves its own instance of the object and does not share one with the parent. When resolving in the parent, the behavior is like a container controlled lifetime; when resolving the parent and the child you have different instances with each acting as a container-controlled lifetime. If you have multiple children, each will resolve its own instance."

`Configuration.DependencyResolver`s container is root container. but controller constructere resolvers container is child container of root container.

```
    IService _service;
    IUnityContainer _container;

    public DefaultController(IService service,IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _service = service;
        _container = container;
    }
```

[image]

so.. you can get same object from injected container..

```
    IService _service;
    IUnityContainer _container;

    public DefaultController(IService service,IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _service = service;
        _container = container;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ResponseObject> Test()
    {
        var localService = _container.Resolve<IService>();
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(_service, localService))
            Debug.WriteLine("Equal");
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("Not Equal");
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this time it doesn't Dispose the service after request completed. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: how did you test it?

Comment: I'm putting a breakpoint on Dispose() funtion, it doesn't catch. Also It doesn't reload the context in the Service. So, my aim is recreating IFirmService and DBContext in the IFirmService for each request.